# Disabling multiple radio buttons at once

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In this component I have a radio button and a text box in a row. When the radio button is selected the input field in that row is enabled. When the radio button is not selected the input field in that row is disabled. How would I do this using react?

```
 <div className="row">
      <input value="one" name="stars" type="radio" />
       <input type="number" className="number-input"/>
   </div>
<div className="row">
      <input value="one" name="stars" type="radio" />
       <input type="number" className="number-input"/>
    </div>
    <div className="row">
      <input value="one" name="stars" type="radio" />
       <input type="number" className="number-input"/>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach might be to track the value using state:

```
  <div className="row">
      <input value="one" name="stars" type="radio" checked={this.state.oneChecked} onChange={e=>this.setState({oneChecked: e.target.checked})}/>
      <input type="number" className="number-input" disabled={!this.state.oneChecked} />
  </div>
  <div className="row">
      <input value="two" name="stars" type="radio" checked={this.state.twoChecked} onChange={e=>this.setState({twoChecked: e.target.checked})}/>
      <input type="number" className="number-input" disabled={!this.state.twoChecked} />
  </div>
  <div className="row">
      <input value="three" name="stars" type="radio" checked={this.state.threeChecked} onChange={e=>this.setState({threeChecked: e.target.checked})}/>
      <input type="number" className="number-input" disabled={!this.state.threeChecked} />
  </div>
```

Comment: I updated my answer to include a more complete example.  I suspect you were trying to use the same state variable for all 3 inputs, which would cause all of the number inputs to stay enabled as you describe

Comment: Lets say you select row two and the switch to row three, row two stays enabled right? Am I not thinking about this correctly?